# Movie about a guy working in a crooked organization

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie a few years ago but can only remember some elements of the plot.

A guy starts working at a new company. I think they were selling stocks over the phone. The company were either selling crooked stocks or else the stocks they were selling all dropped causing all the buyers to lose money.

I can remember two scenes. In the first one the lead goes out to a bar with work colleagues and gets in a brawl with another group of guys.

In the second scene the lead is on the phone with a customer trying to help him either get his money back or sell the stocks before they drop.

I thought Edward Norton played the lead but I went through his Imdb page and couldn't find the movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like [Boiler Room](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181984/).  I'm guessing you're misremembering [Norton](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001570/) as playing [Giovanni Ribisi](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000610/)'s character, [Seth Davis](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0013877/).

Comment: And the "brawl" was really just Scott Caan brutally beating a real broker, since our Boiler Room guys were on a field trip into a Wall Street bar to see how they could make the "honest" guys angry.